# How to add modules in Python?

Tags: python, pypi

In Java, we have a main class who calls the classes and methods when needs. I'm trying to build a Python app with the same style: main file and few .py files with extra functionality.

I can import those files using

```
import <filename without .py>
```

What if I want to put all those files into a `lib` folder? I want to build a package for PyPI with my app.

Comment: I don't get your question. You can put files wherever you want. You can create folders (which is pretty much the same as package in Python) wherever you want. You then define `setup.py` file and you can gather all files into one package format (wheel or whatever).

Comment: Basic packaging tips from docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages  Is that what you look for?

Comment: I guess it may works... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app/
  main.py
  lib/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py

#main.py
from lib import foo
foo.SomeClass()
```

Comment: I tried your solution few days ago, and it doesn't works... I tried it now, and it works. Python is magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, place a `__init__.py` in the directory the modules are in. Then - if your directory's name is `lib` - `import` your file like below from your main file.

```
import lib.foo
lib.foo.hello() # Calls the hello() function in the lib/foo.py file
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all Python files into your lib directory then also add a file called `__init__.py` in that directory. This file is to be left empty.

1. Create a directory: `mkdir lib`
2. Create an empty file in this directory: `touch __init__.py`
3. Create the other modules you want to include in your package in this
   same directory
4. In your shell (e.g. bash) add `lib` to your `$PYTHONPATH`:

   `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/lib"`
5. import all modules in `lib`: Be sure to be one directory level above `lib`, then: `>>> from lib import *`

Comment: your answer would be better if you included an example.